# How to find items with multiple different names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble with a very simple sql query. I want to identify all items that have more than one name. Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
select group_concat(distinct name) names
from table 
group by master_id
having names like '%,%'
```

Unfortunately, a lot of `names` have a `,` in it, so the above doesn't work well. What would be the correct way to do this query?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: What does *'doesn't work well'* exactly mean?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone It returns rows which correspond to a single name containing a comma.

Comment: Then there's already a correct answer+comment if you are looking for more than one distinct names having the same master_id.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you've given the correct answer in your comment below, just doing the `having count(distinct name) > 1`, if you want to put that in an answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a correct version of your query:

```
SELECT
    master_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name) names
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY master_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1;
```

The reason we need to count distinct in the `HAVING` clause is that a logical item in the aggregated string is a *distinct* name.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be:

```
… HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

In a query using `GROUP BY`, aggregate functions like `COUNT()`, `MIN()`, and `MAX()` (as well as `GROUP_CONCAT()`, as well as a few others) can be used to operate on all values of a column in the grouped rows.

You could also include `COUNT(name)` in the columns to return the number of names for the `master_id`.

Comment: It should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name)`, but let's see the data the OP might add to the question.